# how to dynamically (or not) move javascript to the footer

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site, and I need to move some javascript to the footer.  I am using a theme (photocrati) that only uses the wp_enqueue_scripts tag a total of 4 times in the header.php file.

What I'm looking to do is find a way, hopefully dynamically, to move the javascript files to the footer.  I realize this would be much easier using the $in_footer if they were properly referenced using the enqueue_scripts, but alas, that's not the case.

Being that this is a photography studio website, I need to do everything I can to reduce loading time.  Now, obviously I'm not about to move CSS to the footer like google page speed recommends because I don't want my site being rendered unformatted when the visitor first views it.

After doing everything else I can (I obviously can't do anything about minimizing or setting leveraging browser caching on files not hosted with my site, ie the google analytics js file), the page speed insights recommends, "Remove render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content" is all I have left.  I am hoping once I move the js to the footer my page load time will be under 5 seconds considering it is now just under 6 and there are 19 script resources.

Hopefully someone can give me some guidance on being able to do this through some PHP code added to the functions.php file since I (for the most part) understand what's going on with PHP code when I am writing.  But, I am having a hard time deciphering what is going on in the header file, and being able to find all 19 js files to delete them from the header file and enqueue them properly.

*EDIT* Here is the header.php file.  I've noticed that some of the scripts are not even called here in any way because when I search the file for say "hoverintent.js" it's nowhere to be found, but if I search the source code after my page loads, sure enough it's in the header.

```
<?php

$preset = Photocrati_Style_Manager::get_active_preset();

extract($preset->to_array());



$rcp = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT fs_rightclick,lightbox_mode,lightbox_type FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."photocrati_gallery_settings WHERE id = 1");

foreach ($rcp as $rcp) {

    $fs_rightclick = $rcp->fs_rightclick;

    $lightbox_mode = $rcp->lightbox_mode;

    $lightbox_type = $rcp->lightbox_type;

}

$music = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT music_blog,music_blog_auto,music_blog_file,music_blog_controls,music_cat,music_cat_auto,music_cat_file,music_cat_controls FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."photocrati_gallery_settings WHERE id = 1");

foreach ($music as $music) {

    $music_blog = $music->music_blog;

    $music_blog_auto = $music->music_blog_auto;

    $music_blog_controls = $music->music_blog_controls;

    $music_blog_file = $music->music_blog_file;

    $music_cat = $music->music_cat;

    $music_cat_auto = $music->music_cat_auto;

    $music_cat_controls = $music->music_cat_controls;

    $music_cat_file = $music->music_cat_file;

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?> class='ie9'><!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><!--<![endif]-->

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php

Photocrati_Fonts::render_google_font_link(array(

    array($font_style, $font_weight, $font_italic),

    array($sidebar_font_style, $sidebar_font_weight, $sidebar_font_italic),

    array($sidebar_title_style, $sidebar_title_weight, $sidebar_title_italic),

    array($title_style, $title_font_weight, $title_italic),

    array($h1_font_style, $h1_font_weight, $h1_font_italic),

    array($h2_font_style, $h2_font_weight, $h2_font_italic),

    array($h3_font_style, $h3_font_weight, $h3_font_italic),

    array($h4_font_style, $h4_font_weight, $h4_font_italic),

    array($h5_font_style, $h5_font_weight, $h5_font_italic),

    array($description_style, $description_font_weight, $description_font_italic),

    array($menu_font_style, $menu_font_weight, $menu_font_italic),

    array($submenu_font_style, $submenu_font_weight, $submenu_font_italic),

    array($footer_widget_style, $footer_widget_weight, $footer_widget_italic),

    array($footer_font_style, $footer_font_weight, $footer_font_italic)

));

?>

<title><?php

    if ( is_single() ) { single_post_title(); }       

    elseif ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { bloginfo('name'); print ' | '; bloginfo('description'); get_page_number(); }

    elseif ( is_page() ) { single_post_title(''); }

    elseif ( is_search() ) { bloginfo('name'); print ' | Search results for ' . wp_specialchars($s); get_page_number(); }

    elseif ( is_404() ) { bloginfo('name'); print ' | Not Found'; }

    else { bloginfo('name'); wp_title('|'); get_page_number(); }

?></title>



<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />



<!-- IMPORTANT! Do not remove this code. This is used for enabling & disabling the dynamic styling -->

    <?php if($dynamic_style) { ?>



        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/styles/dynamic-style.php" />

        <?php if($logo_menu_position == 'left-right') { ?>

        <!--[if lt IE 8]>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/styles/style-ie7-menufix.css" type="text/css" />

        <![endif]-->

        <?php } ?>



    <?php } else { ?>



        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/styles/style.css" />

        <?php if($logo_menu_position == 'left-right') { ?>

        <!--[if lt IE 8]>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/styles/style-ie7-menufix.css" type="text/css" />

        <![endif]-->

        <?php } ?>



    <?php } ?>

<!-- End dynamic styling -->



<!--[if IE 8]>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/styles/style-ie.css" type="text/css" />

<![endif]-->



<!--[if lt IE 8]>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/styles/style-ie7.css" type="text/css" />

<![endif]-->



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/admin/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" />



<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>



<?php

if( !is_admin()){

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-core');

    if ($preset->custom_js) wp_enqueue_script('photocrati-custom-js', site_url('?photocrati-js'));

 }

?>



<?php wp_head(); ?>



<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( '%s latest posts', 'photocrati-framework' ), wp_specialchars( get_bloginfo('name'), 1 ) ); ?>" />

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="<?php bloginfo('comments_rss2_url') ?>" title="<?php printf( __( '%s latest comments', 'photocrati-framework' ), wp_specialchars( get_bloginfo('name'), 1 ) ); ?>" />

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />



<?php if($fs_rightclick == "ON") { ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/clickprotect.js"></script>

<?php } ?>



<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/jplayer.style.css" />



<?php if($lightbox_type == 'fancy'): ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/admin/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" />

<?php elseif($lightbox_type == 'light'): ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/admin/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4-light.css" type="text/css" />

<?php elseif($lightbox_type == 'thick'): ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/admin/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4-thick.css" type="text/css" />

<?php endif ?>



<?php if($style_skin == 'modern' || $lightbox_type == 'magnific'): ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/admin/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/lightbox/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css" />

<?php endif ?>



<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/admin/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>



<?php if($style_skin == 'modern' || $lightbox_type == 'magnific'): ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/lightbox/magnific-popup/magnific-popup-v0.9.9.min.js"></script>

<?php endif ?>



<?php if($style_skin == 'modern' && is_front_page()): ?>

<?php

// when selecting multiple images as background then $home_bg_image is an array

if (!is_array($home_bg_image)) {

$home_bg_image = array($home_bg_image);

}



$home_bg_list = array();



foreach ($home_bg_image as $bg_image) {

if ($bg_image != null) {

    $bg_img = Photocrati_Style_Manager::get_image_url($bg_image, true);



    if ($bg_img != null) {

        $home_bg_list[] = array(

            'image' => $bg_img,

            'thumb' => Photocrati_Style_Manager::get_image_url($bg_image, true, 'thumbnail'),

            'title' => $bg_image,

        );

    }

}

}



// check that there are 1 or more images selected, otherwise fallback to default

if ($home_bg_list == null) {

$home_bg = 'default';

}



?>

<?php if($home_bg == 'slideshow'): ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?  >/scripts/supersized/slideshow/css/supersized.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/supersized/slideshow/theme/supersized.shutter.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/supersized/slideshow/js/supersized.3.2.7.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/supersized/slideshow/theme/supersized.shutter.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">



        jQuery(function($){



            $.supersized({



                // Functionality

                slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off

                autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically

                start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)

                stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide

                random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)

                slide_interval          :   <?php echo (floatval($home_bg_interval_speed) * 1000) ?>,       // Length between transitions

                transition              :       <?php echo ($home_bg_transition_effect) ?>,             // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left

                transition_speed        :   <?php echo (floatval($home_bg_transition_speed) * 1000) ?>,     // Speed of transition

                new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab

                pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover

                keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off

                performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)

                image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript



                // Size & Position                         

                min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)

                min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)

                vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background

                horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background

                fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)

                fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height

                fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width



                // Components                           

                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')

                thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide

                thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation

                slides                  :   <?php echo json_encode($home_bg_list) ?>,



                // Theme Options               

                progress_bar            :   1,          // Timer for each slide                         

                mouse_scrub             :   0



            });

        });



    </script>
```

There's the part of the header.php file that contains the js file references.  As I said before, not all of them are called through the header.php file.

Comment: You could also add a `defer` attribute to your scripts. It's not supported in IE before version 10, but it could help here too. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: if you have some code to post, we can [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @WhiteHat, I added some of the code.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach, that seems like a viable option,at least for now.  According to W3Schools' statistics less than 2% use IE9 or earlier, and since this is a photography website and loading lots of high-res images, I'm guessing the ones who are wouldn't be hanging around to wait for the images to load anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Enqueue script has a fifth parameter, which is a boolean, false as default. If you set to true, your scripts will be in the footer. In case, your theme has the `wp_footer()` method in the footer.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

An example:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'mysript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array(), false, true ); ?>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer; however, either I'm not understanding your answer or you're not understanding my question.  In my question, I explain that the theme I'm using does not properly use the wp_enqueue_script; therefore, I can't simply use the fifth parameter.